# How to write a loop in R so that after each calculation the number in the variable name is changed and the calculation is performed again

Tags: r

I have a folder with 25 data named smithii1, smithii2...smithii25.csv. In the first step I import smithii1.csv as **sm1** and do some calculations and finally export a number named **angle1**, then I have to repeat this step until I get angle2, angle3...angle25 from the 25 files
[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arNTH.png)
Is there a way to get R to automatically do the above steps and then change the number in the variable name to calculate it again by some loop? I think it's with a for loop.

Here is the script in one round.

```
# read data
sm1 <- read.csv("smithii1.csv", header = TRUE)
# arrange the order to make sure the first pic will be selected then
sm1 <- sm1[order(sm1$number),]
# set central point
a <- 1/2*sm1[1,]$imagewidth
b <- 1/2*sm1[1,]$imageheight
# calculate distance between central point and first tracking point(in pixels)
d1 <- sqrt((sm1[1,]$x-a)^2+(sm1[1,]$y-b)^2)
# calculate the coefficient to transfer pixels into real distance(in meters)
# coefficient r=2*height*tanθ/imagewidth
r1 = 2*sm1[1,]$height*sm1[1,]$model/sm1[1,]$imagewidth
# calculate real distance
d1=d1*r1
# calculate angle
angle1 <- atan(d1/sm1[1,]$height)*180/pi
```

> **Problem solved** by @langtang

```
setwd(folderpath)
paths = dir(pattern = "smith.*csv$")

f <- function(path) {
  sm1 <- read.csv(path, header = TRUE)
  sm1 <- sm1[order(sm1$number),]
  a <- 1/2*sm1[1,]$imagewidth
  b <- 1/2*sm1[1,]$imageheight
  d1 <- sqrt((sm1[1,]$x-a)^2+(sm1[1,]$y-b)^2)
  r1 = 2*sm1[1,]$height*sm1[1,]$model/sm1[1,]$imagewidth
  d1=d1*r1
  angle1 <- atan(d1/sm1[1,]$height)*180/pi
  return(data.frame(file = path, angle=angle1))
}
sm.angle <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(paths, f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put your file names in a vector, and apply a helper function to each name in that vector:

```
paths = dir(pattern = "smith.*csv$")

get_angle <- function(path) {
  # read data
  sm1 <- read.csv(path, header = TRUE)
  <your code here>
  return(dataframe(file = path, angle=angle1))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(paths, get_angle))
```

Comment: Thank you! Your reply is very timely, precise and helpful :)